# Parsing Asterix using Bash Scripting

Tags: bash, unix, awk, cut

I have a string like -
"30 2 *"
How do I use cut/awk in bash scripting to parse the above string into 3 variables delimited by space.
Desired Output: a=30 b=2 c=*

Answer (score 4):

```
$ read -r a b c <<< "30 2 *"; echo "a=$a b=$b c=$c"
a=30 b=2 c=*
```